# Apache Shiro authentication failing second time around

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, authentication, shiro

I have a JavaEE web application that is making use of Apache Shiro for a security framework.  I've implemented a custom JPA authorization realm so I can store my user accounts using JPA.  My custom realm looks something like this...

```
public class JPAAuthorizingRealm extends AuthorizingRealm {

    /**
     * Logger for this class
     */
    private static final Logger logger = Logger
            .getLogger(JPAAuthorizingRealm.class);

    public static final String REALM_NAME = "jpaRealm";

    private UserAccountRepository accountRepository = null;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public JPAAuthorizingRealm() {
        super();

        setName("JpaRealm");
        setAuthenticationCachingEnabled(false);
        setCachingEnabled(false);

        HashedCredentialsMatcher matcher = new HashedCredentialsMatcher();
        matcher.setHashAlgorithmName("SHA-256");
        matcher.setHashIterations(SecurityConstants.PASSWORD_HASH_ITERATIONS);
        setCredentialsMatcher(matcher);

        try {
            BeanManager beanManager = (BeanManager) new InitialContext()
                    .lookup("java:comp/BeanManager");
            Bean<UserAccountRepository> accountRepositoryBean = (Bean<UserAccountRepository>) beanManager
                    .resolve(beanManager.getBeans(UserAccountRepository.class));
            CreationalContext<?> creationalContext = beanManager
                    .createCreationalContext(null);
            UserAccountRepository accountRepository = accountRepositoryBean
                    .create((CreationalContext<UserAccountRepository>) creationalContext);
            this.accountRepository = accountRepository;
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            logger.error(
                    "JPAAuthorizingRealm() - exception while creating user account repository", e); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }
    }

  <snip>
```

I am able to create user accounts (in a separate class) successfully, with a hashed password that can be used to authenticate.  My problem is, I am only able to authenticate ***one time***.  If I login a user, I see that my Shiro `Subject` says I am authenticated.  If I logout, however, and try to log back in using the exact same credentials (or even a different account altogether) the login never seems to be applied.  I see that my `Subject` has `isAuthenticated() == true` immediately after authentication, but on subsequent requests it says `isAuthenticated() == false`.  Even if I open up a completely separate browser I see the same behavior.  Once my first user has successfully logged in, I am unable to login a second user.

My login code looks like this, and is implemented within a stateless EJB...

```
AuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(loginName,
        password);
try {
    this.subject.login(token);
} catch (IncorrectCredentialsException e) {
    logger.error("authenticateUser(String, String)", e); //$NON-NLS-1$

    throw new InvalidCredentialsException(e);
} catch (AuthenticationException e) {
    logger.error("authenticateUser(String, String)", e); //$NON-NLS-1$

    throw new UserAuthenticationException(e);
}
```

My logout code looks like this...

```
SecurityUtils.getSubject().logout();
Faces.invalidateSession();
```

My shiro.ini file looks like this:

```
[main]
# listener = org.apache.shiro.config.event.LoggingBeanListener

authc = org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.PassThruAuthenticationFilter
authc.loginUrl = /login.xhtml

jpaRealm=com.myapp.JPAAuthorizingRealm

[urls]
/login.xhtml = authc
```

Once again, when I authenticate the ***first time***, everything works as expected.  My Subject says I'm authenticated on every request.  If I pull up a separate browser and try to authenticate as a second user, the authentication never goes through.  Any ideas what could be causing this?  I'm somewhat new to Apache Shiro, so it's entirely possible I'm doing something wrong.

**UPDATE:**  I've done a bit more testing, and replaced my custom JPA realm with a standard Shiro JDBC realm just to narrow down where the problem lies.  The new JDBC realm configuration results in the exact same behavior as before.  However, I've now noticed that if I login as **user1** from Browser A (Safari, login successful) successfully, and then try to login as **user2** on a separate browser (Firefox, login *seemingly* unsuccessful) then go *BACK* to Browser A and hit refresh, I see myself authenticated as **user1**.  It seems as though there's some sort of state management issue going on, but I can't for the life of me figure out what.

Here's my new shiro.ini, as well as the CDI producer that I'm using to produce my Subject and SecurityManager objects.  Can ANYONE help me out with this?  It's very frustrating.

shiro.ini:

```
[main]
hashService=org.apache.shiro.crypto.hash.DefaultHashService
hashService.hashIterations=10000
hashService.hashAlgorithmName=SHA-256

passwordService=org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.DefaultPasswordService
passwordService.hashService = $hashService

passwordMatcher=org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.PasswordMatcher
passwordMatcher.passwordService=$passwordService

authc = org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.PassThruAuthenticationFilter
authc.loginUrl = /login.xhtml

jdbcDataSource=org.apache.shiro.jndi.JndiObjectFactory
jdbcDataSource.resourceName=java:jboss/datasources/MyDataSource
jdbcDataSource.resourceRef=true

jdbcRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = SELECT hashedPassword FROM tbl_user_account WHERE loginname = ?
jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled=false
#jdbcRealm.credentialsMatcher = $sha256Matcher
jdbcRealm.credentialsMatcher=$passwordMatcher
jdbcRealm.dataSource = $jdbcDataSource

securityManager.realms = $jdbcRealm

[urls]
/login.xhtml = authc
```

CDI Producer:

```
@Singleton
public class SecurityProducer {

    /**
     * Logger for this class
     */
    private static final Logger logger = Logger
            .getLogger(SecurityProducer.class);

    private org.apache.shiro.mgt.SecurityManager securityManager;

    /**
     * Initializes the {@link org.apache.shiro.mgt.SecurityManager} after bean
     * creation
     */
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("init() - start"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }

        final String iniFile = "classpath:shiro.ini";
        securityManager = new IniSecurityManagerFactory(iniFile).getInstance();
        SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager(securityManager);

        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("init() - end"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }
    }

    /**
     * Produces an Apache Shiro {@link org.apache.shiro.mgt.SecurityManager}
     * 
     * @return The security manager
     */
    @Produces
    @Named("securityManager")
    public org.apache.shiro.mgt.SecurityManager getSecurityManager() {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("getSecurityManager() - start"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }

        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("getSecurityManager() - end"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }
        return securityManager;
    }

    /**
     * Produces an Apache Shiro {@link Subject}
     * 
     * @return The subject
     */
    @Produces
    @Named("subject")
    public Subject getSubject() {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("getSubject() - start"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }

        Subject subject = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("getSubject() - Subject subject=" + subject); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }

        if (subject.isAuthenticated() || subject.isRemembered()) {
            boolean authenticated = subject.isAuthenticated();
            boolean remembered = subject.isRemembered();
            Object principal = subject.getPrincipal();
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("getSubject() - authenticated=" + authenticated + ", remembered=" + remembered + ", principal=" + principal); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$ //$NON-NLS-3$
            }
        } else {
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("getSubject() - User is not authenticated or remembered"); //$NON-NLS-1$
            }
        }

        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("getSubject() - end"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }
        return subject;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your shiro.ini set a web session manager and set that into your security manager. See that helps.

```
sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
securityManager.sessionManager = $sessionManager
```

Comment: I had the same issue, this did it for me. Plus, now I can access all the config options like HttpOnly header from shiro.ini. (Oh well, Shiro noob...)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it simple by cleaning the cache and cookies from local-host (or whatever is the server address) at the browser.
None of the suggestions above worked for me.